Microsoft Graph REST API Create a new item in a list
Nice to meet you everyone
I'm Japanese and can't speak English at all, so I'm using Google Translate to post my questions.
I think there are some parts that are difficult to understand, but I would appreciate it if you could help me solve it.
Now on to the main topic
I'm currently trying to register a new item using the Microsoft Graph REST API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
However, the reference example is not enough for what I want to achieve, so if anyone knows how to set the items, please let me know.
Target columns include images, hyperlinks, locations, managed metadata, and attachments.I'm having trouble figuring out how to set these fields.
After searching, it seems that these columns may not be supported by GraphAPI yet, so if anyone knows about this, please let me know.
Example
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "fields": {
        "hyperlinkColumnName": {
            "Description": "hyperlinkName",
            "Url": "https://aaa.com"
        }
    }
}


Creating hyperlink field is still not supported

Hyperlink column update is not supported in MS Graph yet. You can use the SharePoint rest api to create/update hyperlink columns.
Here is the sample code to update a hyperlink column:
self.UpdateHyperLink = function(id, state) {
 var data = {
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.HyperLinkListItem' },
    'HyperLink_x0020_Page': 
            {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
                'Description': 'LinkTitle',
                'Url': 'http://Link.com'
            },
    'State': state
};
var url = "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<listguid>')/Items(" + id + ")";
var promise = $.ajax({
    'url': url,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
});
return promise;

};

thank you!
It's still not supported. . .
